# Why am I getting the last sum as largest sum of subarray?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void printpair(int ar[], int n)
{
    int largestsum = INT_MIN, currentsum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            currentsum = 0;
            largestsum = INT_MIN;
            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
            {
                cout << ar[k] << ",";
                currentsum += ar[k];
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
        largestsum = max(largestsum, currentsum);
        cout << "the largest sum is " << largestsum << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int ar[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> ar[i];
    printpair(ar, n);
}
```

When I input:

```
5
-5 5 6 -7 1
```

I'm getting output from the first iteration of the outer loop as

```
-5,
-5,5,
-5,5,6,
-5,5,6,-7,
-5,5,6,-7,1,
the largest sum is 0
...
```

But it should be `6` as `-5 + 5 + 6 = 6` so the largest sum of subarray must be `6`, but here it is `0`, why!?

Comment: Using both ``#include <bits/stdc++.h>; using namespace std;`` is a really bad idea. Please don't do it for your own sake.

Comment: `int ar[n];` is illegal in standard C++ (without compiler extensions) since the value of `n` needs to be known at compile time, not run time. Instead prefer `std::vector<int> ar(n);`

Comment: it is unclear how you can get the reported output with the posted code. As `cout << "the largest sum is " << largestsum << endl;` is inside the loop you print it for each element not only for the last

Comment: this is the output i get from your code https://godbolt.org/z/ns91zTar5

Comment: You reinit `currentsum`, `largestsum` in `j-loop`, so `currentsum ` is only the last sum from `k-loop`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes in the first i loop i'm getting 0 as largest sum but it should be 6 as largest sum

Comment: Well this seems like a great opportunity to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the max sum value, you need to do it within the loop:

```
void printpair(int ar[], int n)
{
    int largestsum = INT_MIN, currentsum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            currentsum = 0;
            largestsum = INT_MIN;
            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
            {
                std::cout << ar[k] << ",";
                currentsum += ar[k];
                largestsum = std::max(largestsum, currentsum);
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "the largest sum is " << largestsum << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that variable length arrays are not C++ standard, you should not use them, I would also advise you not to use `using namespace std;` and `#include <bits/stdc++.h>;`, here are some threads with more on these matters:

[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/6865932)

[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6865932)

[Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/6865932)

Comment: hm... isnt `if (largestsum < currentsum) ...` and `largestsum = max(largestsum, currentsum)` somewhat redundant?

Comment: now this line is not much needed:  largestsum = max(largestsum, currentsum);

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number lol, you have to give me some credit here, I'm looking at this in my phone.

Comment: now this is printing largest sum for each starting index, but not determining the largest sum of subarray (for any startign index)

Comment: better to not spoon feed it all at once

Answer (score 0):

You are setting

```
          largestsum = INT_MIN;
```

in the inner loop.

Comment: yes to reset the largest sum value for next subarray